# Scala function, unexpected behaviour

Tags: scala, list, loops

I have the following Scala code snippet:

`(1 to 10).foreach(a => (1 to 100 by 3).toList.count(b => b % a == 0))`

which, I would expect to behave like the following:

- Create a list of multiple of 3 less than 100
- For each item in the list previously generated, count how many multiples of 1, 2, 3... 10 there are

But, when I run the snippet, I get an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Because `foreach` lets you do a side effect for each value; in this case you'll want to `map`.
Moreover your statement of the algorithm is not correct.

Comment: When you see `()`, that's not an empty list, it's the [`Unit`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html) singleton type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior is totally expect when using `foreach`.

`foreach` takes a procedure — a function with a result type `Unit` — as the right operand. It simply applies the procedure to each List element. The result of the operation is again `Unit`; no list of results is assembled.

It's typically used for its side effects — something like printing or saving into a database, etc.

You ought using `map` instead :

```
scala> (1 to 10).map(a => (1 to 100 by 3).toList.count(b => b % a == 0))
// res3: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(34, 17, 0, 9, 7, 0, 5, 4, 0, 4)
```